# Can functional dependencies be "inversed"

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Say I have a situation where a person who is uniquely defined by their `firstName` and `lastName` can rent a car uniquely defined by its `licensePlateNumber` and `dayOfRental`.

Can I say both of these statements capture the domain requirement?

```
firstName, lastName -> licensePlateNumber, dayOfRental 
licensePlateNumber, dayOfRental -> firstName, lastName
```

Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: If the relation is `one to one` then it should.

Comment: What do you mean by one-to-one. Sorry I'm a beginner in this DBMS subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's *clearly* a difference between {firstName, lastName}->{licensePlateNumber, type} and {licensePlateNumber, type}->{firstName, lastName}. In symbolic notation, you'd have A->B and B->A. Those two are clearly different.

Second, both those together do seem to capture the requirement you're interested in.

Third, I'd expect license plate number alone to uniquely identify a car. But that doesn't change the substance of your question or of my answer.

Comment: Ah that's my fault, I made this example up. I couldn't think of anything that is rented that is uniquely identified by two attributes haha. Also, I just wanted to clarify something, I will post it in another comment...

Comment: You say it captures the requirement I'm interested, so that leads me to believe that your answer could be different depending on how I word my requirement. See my edit: I changed the `color` attribute to `dayOfRental`. For example, if I say my requirement is: *A car cannot be rented by more than one person on the same day*. I get the feeling that it is more appropriate to say `licensePlateNumber, dayOfRental -> firstName, lastName` instead of the other one. But I dont know if the other one is right too.

Comment: Your edit didn't really change anything substantial. The two are still different, and you still have A->B and B->A. (A->B doesn't mean the same thing as B->A.)